# Intersecting of two sets (SVG or canvas in HTML5)

Tags: jquery, svg, geometry, html5-canvas, intersection

I would like to draw an intersection of two sets as overlapping (or not) two circles with the same radius.

For example, based on the following input data:

- **intersection = 1**,
- **circle1 = 0**,
- **circle2 = 3**

I would get:
http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/7813/53261474.jpg

In case my input data is:

- **intersection = 59**,
- **circle1 = 0**,
- **circle2 = 0**

I will get: http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/319/95092557.png

How can I achieve this? Should I use SVG or canvas? Is it possible to apply some animation  of those balls (e.g. maybe some random moves within their intersected/difference area) on load when the document is ready. Ideally I would use jQuery.

Thank you for your kindest!

Comment: I would recommend having a look at http://d3js.org.

Comment: Randomizing the dots will be harder than distributing them regularly. Is that important? And to be clear, it's always only two circles?

Comment: @Phrogz there will always be two circles. Dots can be distributed regularly, as well. It doesn't matter unless they cross their borders.